# Can an AuthorizationAttribute prevent an action from being executed entirely?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorization

I've got a custom AuthorizationAttribute that appeared to be working on the surface.  When a user without the correct permissions requests an action via the browser, they are shown the appropriate message.

I started applying this attribute to `HttpPost` actions that do things like delete.  Even though the response is correct, the body of the action still executes (in this instance the item is deleted).

What I want to be able to do is completely prevent the action method from doing anything if the authorization attribute fails.  Is this what AuthorizationAttributes are for, or should I looking at another way?

**Update:**

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    Check.Require(filterContext != null);

    if (service.HasPermission(requiredPermission))
        return;

    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = "File not found";
}
```

The controller action is being decorated like this:

```
[HttpPost, RequiresPermission(Permissions.CanDeleteContentItem)]
public JsonResult Delete(Guid id)
```

Comment: Can you post some code?  The Authorize attribute doens't work the way your describing.

Comment: Added the `OnAuthorization` method and the action signature

Comment: This was essentially a way to get around having to write a permission check block of code at the top of each action method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing something very similar in my many MVC projects, except that I'm not deriving from `AuthorizeAttribute`, I'm deriving from `ActionFilterAttribute` and just working with `OnActionExecuting`.

Comment: Just use the Boolean IsAuthorized method to return false. It will be called after your OnAuthorization. You can flag it in the OnAuthorization method and save it in a field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511496/asp-net-mvc-ticket-required-attribute/4512257#4512257) as it's similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

What you need to do is change the result that is returned by the action instead of just changing the header values.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    Check.Require(filterContext != null);

    if (service.HasPermission(requiredPermission))
        return;

    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, {"action", "NoPermission" } })
}
```

### Update

You can also just do the following if you would like to return the proper HTTP response:

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

Comment: Don't want the user to be redirected to the login page - to an unauthorized user it should appear as though the page just doesn't exist.  Cheers though for adding an update after I'd accepted the answer.